# How to get correct links in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url

I uploaded my laravel project to subfolder, but something went wrong to my links. Now my url is site.com/laravel
For example:

```
<a href="/">Index</a>
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

When I click on Index or About - Laravel redirecting me to `site.com` not to `site.com/laravel`

How to correct this?

Comment: You can define like below.

<a href="/laravel/">Index</a>
<a href="/laravel/about">About</a>

Comment: set a base meta tag, like so: `<base href="http://www.example.com/laravel/">`. See [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Comment: use laravel route function to link

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{url('/')}}">Index</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your route named you can use

```
<a href="{{route('home')}}">Index</a>
<a href=""{{route('about')}}">About</a>
```

otherwise

```
<a href="{{url('/')}}">Index</a>
<a href="{{url('about')}}">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{{url('/')}}` for index and `{{url('/about')}}` to about.

For linking to your assets file use

```
{{ asset('path/to/assets/asset.ext') }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls